# Missing Directory API Client Library for Java, Directory API samples and Directory API client libraries

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-admin-sdk

Do you happen to know of an alternative way to get the Directory API Client Library for Java, this page: http://goo.gl/4aB2d shows the link to Download the latest version of the library but it does not work.
Moreover, the Directory API samples and Directory API client libraries don't seem to work either for Java, http://goo.gl/zBTlL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a mistake on the developer site. The team is aware of it and working on fixing the links. In the mean time you can find the download URLs here -

```
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/admin/directory_v1/java
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/admin/reports_v1/java
```

Comment: Thank you Arun, that soleves part of the problem, I do not have the Directory API samples though. Can you help with this too?

Comment: In the python client library, there is a folder inside apiclient that includes all the pydoc.  It is very helpful!

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/admin/directory_v1/python